# Почему не могу настроить слайдер Slick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js, slider-slick.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код слайдера хочу чтоб после 510 зделать простой мод с чтоб по 1 слайду крутилось прописал вроде правильные брейкпоинты но все равно не работаеть

```
            $(".center_two").slick({
             centerMode: true,
             arrows: false,
             centerPadding: "-25px",
             slidesToShow: 2,
             responsive: [
              {
              breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
               arrows: false,
                centerMode: true,
              centerPadding: "10px",
              slidesToShow: 2,
           },
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 713,
           settings: {
           arrows: false,
           centerMode: true,
             centerPadding: "160px",
            slidesToShow: 1,
         },
       },
         {
         breakpoint: 680,
           settings: {
          arrows: false,
           centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: "140px",
          slidesToShow: 1,
        },
   },
{
  breakpoint: 641,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "120px",
    slidesToShow: 1,
  },
},
,
{
  breakpoint: 641,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "100px",
    slidesToShow: 1,
      },
       },
     {
    breakpoint: 629,
   settings: {
     arrows: false,
    centerMode: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
  },
},
{
  breakpoint: 619,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "30px",
    slidesToShow: 1,
  },
},
{
  breakpoint: 597,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "100px",
    slidesToShow: 1,
  },
},
{
  breakpoint: 555,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "100px",
    slidesToShow: 1,
  },
},
{
  breakpoint: 555,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "75px",
    slidesToShow: 1,
  },
},
{
  breakpoint: 509,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "55px",
    slidesToShow: 1,
  },
},
{
  breakpoint: 512,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  settings: {
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "35px",
  },
},
{
  breakpoint: 495,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: false,
    centerPadding: "-10px",
    slidesToShow: 1,
  },
},
{
  breakpoint: 480,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "70px",
    slidesToShow: 1,
  },
},
{
  breakpoint: 414,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "60px",
    slidesToShow: 1,
  },
},
{
  breakpoint: 390,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "50px",
    slidesToShow: 1,
  },
},
{
  breakpoint: 372,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "38px",
    slidesToShow: 1,
  },
},
{
  breakpoint: 372,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "30px",
    slidesToShow: 1,
  },
},
```

],
});

Comment: ну как минимум 2 запятых подряд, это уже ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Все работает:

```js
$(".center_two").slick({
  centerMode: true,
  arrows: false,
  centerPadding: "-25px",
  slidesToShow: 2,
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "10px",
        slidesToShow: 2,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 713,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "160px",
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 680,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "140px",
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 641,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "120px",
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    }, ,
    {
      breakpoint: 641,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "100px",
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 629,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 619,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "30px",
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 597,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "100px",
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 555,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "100px",
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 555,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "75px",
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 509,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "55px",
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 512,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      settings: {
        infinite: true,
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "35px",
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 495,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: false,
        centerPadding: "-10px",
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "70px",
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 414,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "60px",
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 390,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "50px",
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 372,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "38px",
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 372,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "30px",
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slick-slide {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="center_two">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Возможно Вам стоит привести всю разметку, возможно в стилях проблема.